# R Multiply specific rows and columns by constant

Tags: r, multiplication

I have the following data:

```
type <- c(1:4)
year1 <- c(1:4)
year2 <- c(1:4)
year3 <- c(1:4)
data <- data.frame(type, year1, year2, year3)
```

I want to multiply the bottom two rows within Year columns by two.

```
type <- c(1:4)
year1 <- c(1, 2, 6, 8)
year2 <- c(1, 2, 6, 8)
year3 <- c(1, 2, 6, 8)
final <- data.frame(type, year1, year2, year3)
```

How do I do this without affecting the other rows of columns?

Comment: `data[3:4,]*2`?

Comment: `data[3:4, -1] <- 2 * data[3:4, -1]`

Comment: A very flexible approach would be: `data[(nrow(data)-1):nrow(data),]<- data[(nrow(data)-1):nrow(data),grep(pattern="year",x=names(data))]*2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. This would allow you to tweak the parameters if you like.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

newdata <- data %>%
  gather(., year, value, year1:year3) %>%
  mutate(newvalue = ifelse(type > 2, value * 2, value)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(., year, newvalue)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your logic here in your solution. What's particularly confusing to me is your use of the `value` argument within the `gather()` function. What line of thinking lead you to use the `gather()` function and how does the `value` argument play a role in the solution here? I'm having a similar problem and am trying to adapt this to my own particular situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't know the length of the data and if you wanted to multiply all columns that have "year" in them you could do:

```
data[(nrow(data)-1):nrow(data),]<-data[(nrow(data)-1):nrow(data),grep(pattern="year",x=names(data))]*2

  type year1 year2 year3
1    1     1     1     1
2    2     2     2     2
3    6     6     6     6
4    8     8     8     8
```